# parseInt in Java results to NumberFormatException

Tags: java, numberformatexception

I am trying to load info from a properties file and i have the following code:

```
int minute = Integer.parseInt(prop.getProperty("delay"));
int hour = Integer.parseInt(prop.getProperty("period"));
```

and while the first line works just fine, the second one where i am trying to load a int variable throws a NumberFormatException. The specific exception message is:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1 "
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
```

Currently, In my properties file value of delay is 1 and period is 5.

And when I run this program and prints value of minute and hour it is working fine, but in my Tomcat log console exception above occurs. Please help me to solve this problem? thanks in advance!

Comment: what value are return from prop.getProperty("delay") and prop.getProperty("period")???

Comment: Please check that you have an extra space in "1 "

Comment: delay is 1 and period is 5. @YeWin But I am sure that there isn't any extra space after these values in my config file

Comment: @BornForJava probably you have a space after 1 in property file - "1 " Which causing the NumberFormatException. Please have a look at this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There appears to be trailing white space in your property (since you get `"1 "` in the `Exception`). You could call [`String.trim()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim%28%29) which *Returns a copy of the string, with leading and trailing whitespace omitted*. Something like

```
int minute = Integer.parseInt(prop.getProperty("delay").trim());
int hour = Integer.parseInt(prop.getProperty("period").trim());
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
    String delay = prop.getProperty("delay");
    String period = prop.getProperty("period");
    int minute = Integer.parseInt((delay != null && !delay.trim().isEmpty()) ? delay : "0");
    int hour = Integer.parseInt((period != null && !period.trim().isEmpty()) ? period : "0");
```

`prop.getProperty("delay")` or `prop.getProperty("period")` may be null or empty so you have to check whether the formating string should not be null or empty and not contain any space.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing non-numeric values:

```
int minute = Integer.parseInt(prop.getProperty("delay").replaceAll("\\D",""));
int hour = Integer.parseInt(prop.getProperty("period").replaceAll("\\D",""));
```